# Criteria for operators to have infinitely many eigenvalues

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory

Normal compact linear operators on Hilbert spaces have infinitely many (counting multiplicities) eigenvalues by the spectral theorem.

For non-normal operators this no longer has to be true.
There exist even examples of compact operators without eigenvalues such as weighted shifts and the Volterra operator $Tf(t) = \int_0^t f(s) \ ds$ on $L^2(0,1),$ which when applied to a polynomial basis can also be interpreted as a shift. So a perhaps bold guess would be that we want to avoid some generalized infinite Jordan blocks.

*I would therefore like to understand: Do there exist other criteria not assuming normality that imply the existence of infinitely many eigenvalues for compact operators on Hilbert spaces?*

Comment: It is still true (for non-normal $T$) that any $z\in\sigma(T)$, $z\not= 0$ is an eigenvalue, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory_of_compact_operators#Compact_operators

Comment: So $T$ has infinitely many eigenvalues if and only if $\sigma(T)$ is infinite.

Comment: The zero operator has infinitely many eigenvalues  in the sense of this query (quote: "counting multiplicities").

Comment: @bathalf15320: Still the same thing essentially: Then $T$ has infinitely many eigenvalues if and only if the kernel is infinite-dimensional or $\sigma(T)$ is infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only criterion I know is based on a Theorem in the second book of Dunford and Schwartz, see Theorem X1.6.29 and following. If the resolvent of an Hilbert-Schimdt operator satisfies some decay estimates on some rays dividing the complex plane,  then the span of the generalized eigenfuntions is dense. The theorem generalizes to operators having trace-class powers and to closed operators with trace-class powers of the  resolvent.