# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of non-symmetric elliptic operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvector

We know that the operator $A=\Delta$ with domain $D(A)=\{u\in W^{2, 2}(\Omega): u=0 \ \ \text{on } \partial\Omega\}$ (say $\Omega$ is a bounded nice domain) has eigenvalues $\lambda_1>\lambda_2\ge \cdots \lambda_n\ge$ with corresponding eigenvectors $\{\phi_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\{\phi_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ can be normalized to be an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\Omega)$.

Questions: if $A$ is not symmetric. Say $A=\Delta + a\partial_x$, where $a\in C(\bar\Omega)$. Can the eigenvectors of $A$ still form an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\Omega)$? My guess is if $(\lambda-A)^{-1}$ is normal, then we can apply the spectral theory for compact normal operators. But is  $(\lambda-A)^{-1}$  normal for large $\lambda$? Thanks!!!

Comment: I believe that this convection diffusion operator is a good examples of a non-normal operator for which the spectral theory is more complicated. See the first couple of pages of the introduction of this survey: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.4844.pdf

Comment: See also this related post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409944/criteria-for-operators-to-have-infinitely-many-eigenvalues?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I think I found a counter example: $\Delta (U\phi)/U=\lambda \phi$